# Given pressure in Pascals and temp in Kelvin what equation determines the weight of a volume of air?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass, ideal-gas

I'm trying to determine how many kg of air that a Zeppelin displaces.

1. The volume of the airship is 58142.1 meters cubed.
2. The temperature of the air is 276.26 kelvin.
3. The pressure in pascals is 42,178.

Air is 78 % nitrogen and 21 % oxygen.

1 mole of nitrogen gas has a mass of 28 grams.

1 mole of oxygen gas has a mass of 32 grams.

By subtracting the weight of the empty Zeppelin from the weight of the displaced air it will give me the maximum payload the Zeppelin can carry as cargo.

Although I'm sure the equation is straightforward I can't find it anywhere.  Calculators are online but I'd prefer to be able to calculate this myself so I can put it in Excel.

Comment: Air is 78% nitrogen and 21% oxygen.  The weight of that air is proportional to the volume of air that is displaced.

Comment: @DavidWhite Actually a very good point.  I didn't think of that.  Is there a simple equation to determine the weight of Nitrogen and Oxygen of a given volume at a specific temp and air pressure?  I'll break it up 78% / 21% as you said.

Comment: You need to work out a table where you calculate the weight of the total moles of oxygen displaced and add it to the weight of the total moles of nitrogen displaced.  Do you know enough chemistry to do that?

Comment: @DavidWhite I know that a mole of Oxygen gas is 32 grams and a mole of Nitrogen gas is 28 grams.  But how I plug that into an equation that determines the mass of a volume at a given temp and pressure I'm not sure.  I added your info into my question.

Comment: I hope the atmospheric pressure is greater than 42 kPa or we are all dead!

Comment: @myNewAccount, you can calculate an average molar mass for air and use that in the ideal gas equation.  28.84 g/mole is a good number to use.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 2):

Use gas equation:$PV=nRT$
P is pressure
V is volume
n is average number of moles
R is universal gas constant(you can look up for its value in appropriate units)
T is temperature

You can get n from this equation.
For a mixture of nitrogen and oxygen in ratio 78:21, we have
$$n_{avg}=\frac{78n_{N_2} + 21n_{O_2}}{100}$$

Comment: What is the point of n_{avg} ? n is the total moles and oxygen mole fraction in air is 21 %

Answer (score -2):

Let, m denote the mass of air and M denote the avg. molar mass of air . Then,
$$m = ρV$$
For an ideal gas$$PV=nRT$$
$$PV=(W/M)RT$$
$$ρ=W/V = PM/RT$$
$$m=(PM/RT)V$$

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation.